# CTRL + P in IE using Jquery

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, iframe

Is there a way to set the IFrame as the printing page when pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> in IE.

I have already done this code that works in Chrome, and Firefox.

```
jQuery(document).bind("keyup keydown", function (e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 80) {
        IframePrint();
        return false;
    }
});

function IframePrint() {
    var con = $('form').eq(0);
    con.find('#print').remove();
    var iframe = '<iframe src="CompanyPDFPrint" id="printiframe"    style="display:none;width:0;height:0" name="printiframe"></iframe>';
    con.append(iframe);
    window.frames["printiframe"].print();
}
```

When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, the one that is print is the web page itself.

Is there a way?

Comment: why don't you use a [CSS exclusive for printing](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/)? and hide all the unnecessary blocks and show the ones that matter, instead of hacking yourself in javascript...?

Comment: that can't do cause were using iframe on our printing. The only problem is when we use IE, it prints the webpage not the iframe.

Comment: IE is a bit*** that's why I always play safe when working with it. in your `@media print` you can easily hide all elements and copy the iframe contents to a new element in the page and show it, then it will only print what you want.

Comment: hmm let me think about it. thanks.